# can't show icons with coreUi

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm discovering coreUI.

I'm trying to create this login.html found on github:
https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template/blob/master/Static_Full_Project_GULP/pages-login.html

Everything works great but can't show the user-icon and the lock-icon. Instead, i get the default icon for both of them.

I'm working on a folder named coreUI that contains:

- login.html
- css folder (contains style.css and simple-line-icons.css both from the git repo)
- bower_components folder ( that contains jquery, bootstarp and tether)

so the paths should be correct.

Moreover, when I inspect the element in the browser, i can see in the css rules tab, the content `\e08e` and `\e005` for the lock-icon and the user-icon.
 But they are displaying the same default icon. Any help would be appreciated.

I also tried it with register.html ; https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template/blob/master/Static_Full_Project_GULP/pages-register.html but the same problem. All icons show defaut.

this is my login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="...">
    <meta name="author" content="....">
    <meta name="keyword" content="....">

    <!-- FavIcon link-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.png">
    <!-- Icons -->
    <link href="css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Login</title>



</head>

<body class="app flex-row align-items-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-group mb-0">
                    <div class="card p-4">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h1>Sign In</h1>
                            <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group mb-4">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Login</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6 text-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card card-inverse card-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style="width:44%">
                        <div class="card-block text-center">
                            <div>
                                <h2>Sign up</h2>
                                <p>Site description....</p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active mt-3">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have not either added font folder or fonts in font directory.

SO create a folder fonts add fonts files of simple icon. if you have already font folder then add fonts in this folder.[image]

Comment: you have used "simple-line-icons.css" file to render fonts. it will render only if you  add all fonts of simle line in fonts folder. because user-icon and the lock-icon. icons are special fonts which are rendered from simple-line-icons.css file

Answer (score 0):

This is how your angular.json should look if you want to use @coreui/icons

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.sass",
              "node_modules/@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.css",
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/all.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting in angular.json maybe listing free:

```
 "styles": [
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/free.css",
```

Change to :

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/@coreui/icons/css/all.css",
```